# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK Issues - error

Tags: plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am having the following issue with Microsoft dynamics crm 2013:

I have two parent entities (legal contract or agreement) that reference amendments and financial details in a 1:M relationship.  I need to sum amounts on the child records and store that amount on the parent record.

I wrote a plugin that fires on create, update and delete for each of the child entities.

What has to happen is the following:

1. Find out if my parent is a Legal Contract or an Agreement
2. Sum all of the child record amounts
3. Find the parent and store the summed values.

Problems:
Microsoft has removed the ability to get information from sub-grid components in the new SDK so even though the client has the data available, it is not accessible.

When I run the below code I get an exception on the parentID that is null: the " If (c.Attributes.Contains(...) " test causes an exception.

If I run the same code as command line it works fine, it is only when running as a plugin that it pukes.

Code snippet:

```
         EntityReference parentAgreementId = new EntityReference();
         EntityReference parentContractId = new EntityReference();
         QueryByAttribute querybyattribute = new QueryByAttribute("new_invoicedetails");
                 querybyattribute.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

                 //  Attribute to query.

                querybyattribute.Attributes.AddRange("new_invoicedetailsid");

                 //  Value of queried attribute to return.

                querybyattribute.Values.AddRange(sItem.getChildId());

                 //  Query passed to service proxy.
                 EntityCollection retrieved = service.RetrieveMultiple(querybyattribute);

                 //  Iterate through returned collection.
                 foreach (var c in retrieved.Entities)
                 {
                     If (c.Attributes.Contains("new_contractnumberid"))
                     {
                         parentContractId = c.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_contractnumberid");
                     }

                     If (c.Attributes.Contains("new_agreementnumberid"))
                     {
                         parentAgreementId = c.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_agreementnumberid");
                     }
```

Exception:

-2147220891
        
            
            OperationStatus
            0
        
        
            SubErrorCode
            -2146233088
        
    
            An error occured in the plug-in.
    2014-02-24T20:27:31.028313Z

```
[Contracts.Plugins: Contracts.Plugins.Autonumber]
[97f9577d-1394-e311-a461-000c29f9727b: PostInvoiceDetailsUpdate]
Execption: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Contracts.Plugins.SumAmounts.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
Execption: An error occured in the plug-in.    at Contracts.Plugins.SumAmounts.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at Contracts.Plugins.Autonumber.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that If should be written as if (in lowercase). Am I wrong?

Comment: Lower case "if statement" did not influence outcome.

Comment: What exception do you get? Could you post it here?